# JavaScript - variable not defined

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I am trying to figure out what was wrong with this code:

```
function toggle_visibility() {
    var dropDownNav = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownNav");
    if (dropDownNav.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else dropDownNav.style.display = 'block';
}
```

The HTML goes like this:

```
 <a class="dropDownNavButton" href="#" onclick=
"toggle_visibility(dropDownNav)"><img alt="menu icon" src=
"img/navIcon.png"></a>

<ul class="dropDownNav">
    <li class="liWorks">
        <a href="works.html">Works</a>
    </li>

    <li class="liAbout">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>

    <li class="liContact">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>

    <li class="liBlog">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And yet Chrome tells me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: dropDownNav is not defined
onclick

Could anybody show me the way?

---

Thanks alot for all the quick answers! First time using stackoverflow, definitely not the last. It finally worked, I added the index[0] for the array, and removed dropDownNav on the onClick function. The only problem is, I would like the dropDownNav display to go back to none when I click on the  a second time. Any clue?

Comment: Try it with `dropDownNav[0].style.display`

Comment: Why do you pass undefined `dropDownNav` to `toggle_visibility`?

Comment: You also have to move `var dropDownNav = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownNav");` outside the function.

Comment: @thebreiflabb - why does he have to move it outside the function?

Comment: Never mind that actually, I saw he used `dropDownNav` as an argument in the onclick attribute, which would be undefined unless it was outside the function. But I can see he is not using it inside the function.

Comment: Thanks alot for all the quick answers! First time using stackoverflow, definitely not the last.

It finally worked, I added the index[0] for the array, and removed dropDownNav on the onClick function.

The only problem is, I would like the dropDownNav display to go back to none when I click on the <a> a second time.

Any clue?

Comment: The same function? `<a href="..." onclick="toggle_visibility();">foobar</a>`

Comment: Nevermind, I made it work. I had forgotten to correct part of the function script. Thanks again!

Comment: Question unclear, What do you want to achieve with this code ??

Answer (score 5):

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an HTMLCollection(similar to an array) of all elements matching the class name. The style property is not defined for **HTMLCollection** but for **Element**. Get the first element from the array using

```
var dropDownNav = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDownNav")[0];
```